# Why is my model not getting populated with properties found in dropdownlists?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form that uses the `POST` method to a send data to the `Create` action (annotated with `[HttpPost]`) on my controller. The action signature takes a `Visit`. The problem is only some of the properties on the `Visit` are populated, despite ALL properties being populated on screen in the view. Only the properties where data is input into a textbox are populated. None of the values from dropdownlists are being passed to the model.

Any ideas what's going on here? Thanks!

MVC 4 Beta.

Update 1- the form used in the view...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Visit</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visit.VisitDate)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Visit.VisitDate, new { @class = "editor-field-medium" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.VisitDate)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visit.NPN)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Visit.NPN, new { @class = "editor-field-medium" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.NPN)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visit.AppointmentTypeId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @* THIS DOES NOT GET POPULATED WHEN PASSED TO THE ACTION*@
                @Html.DropDownList("AppointmentTypeId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.AppointmentTypeId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visit.EducationId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @* THIS DOES NOT GET POPULATED WHEN PASSED TO THE ACTION*@
                @Html.DropDownList("EducationId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.EducationId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visit.PsychologistId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @* THIS DOES NOT GET POPULATED WHEN PASSED TO THE ACTION*@
                @Html.DropDownList("PsychologistId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.PsychologistId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visit.PsychometristId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @* THIS DOES NOT GET POPULATED WHEN PASSED TO THE ACTION*@
                @Html.DropDownList("PsychometristId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.PsychometristId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visit.PostDoctoralId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @* THIS DOES NOT GET POPULATED WHEN PASSED TO THE ACTION*@
                @Html.DropDownList("PostDoctoralId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.PostDoctoralId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visit.BehavioralObservations)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Visit.BehavioralObservations)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.BehavioralObservations)
            </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create Visit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? How is the view, model, and controller action look like?

Comment: Can you post the code of your model/viewmodel and of your view?

Answer (score 1):

Your model state is probably invalid. This is an extension method that will read model state and dump errors to the debug log:

```
public static class ModelExtensions
{
    public static void DumpErrors(this System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary ModelState)
    {
        var errors = from key in ModelState
                     let errorList = ModelState[key.Key].Errors
                     where errorList.Any()
                     select new
                     {
                         Item = key.Key,
                         Value = key.Value,
                         errorList
                     };

        foreach (var errorList in errors)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MODEL ERROR:");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorList.Item);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorList.Value);
            foreach (var error in errorList.errorList)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.Exception);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----");
        }
    }
}
```

Call it on the first line of the action having an issue, put a breakpoint in, and see what it says.

```
ModelState.DumpErrors();
```

Comment: DumpErrors() sent nothing to the output window. And the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` condition that wraps my EF `.SaveChanges()` is true (ModelState is valid).

Comment: Hm. Ok, fire up fiddler2, and examine the Request. Is the data populated in the form data?

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown lists aren't populated with anything. You've got:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AppointmentTypeId", String.Empty)
```

So you've got not options to select from. The property `AppointmentTypeId` of your `Visit` will always be empty. Your select list should be populated with options which have relevant text and values:

**View**

```
@{
    List<Appointment> appointmentTypes = ViewBag.AppointmentTypeOptions;
    var appointmentList = new SelectList(list, "AppointmentID", "Description");
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AppointmentTypeId, appointmentList)
```

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.AppointmentTypeOptions = someDataStore.getAppointmentTypes();
```

Note I've used `ViewBag` to make this simpler and allow to keep using your Visit class in your HTTP post. You could create a ViewModel to hold the information for these lists if you liked.

Answer (score 0):

Use one property to map to and one to contain available options...such as PsychometristId and a list of Psychometrists. Then use DropDownListFor instead of DropDownList. 
Try something like this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor("PsychometristId", new SelectList(Psychometrists, "name", "id"))
```